# Deploying R shiny to IBM Cloud server

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, rstudio-server, watson-studio

I have an R shiny application which runs on shinny server. 
I want to run my R shiny application on IBM Cloud server how can i do it?

1)I have R package.

2) I have installed r studio server.

3)I have set Inbound security rules to it.

4)created username and password for it.

followed these steps:
https://console.bluemix.net/docs/infrastructure/security-groups/sg_guidelines.html#security-groups-guidelines

I want this application created to run on IBM Cloud server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [blog article that walks through deploying a R shiny app to IBM Cloud](https://medium.com/ibm-data-science-experience/create-r-shiny-web-apps-with-data-science-experience-and-bluemix-bbf51c0bf4db). The key is to use a special buildpack (`buildpack: git://github.com/beibeiyang/cf-buildpack-r.git` in your manifest file) for deploying the app.

Comment: A small doubt. I am getting time out error while installing the package

`Error staging application TestApp: timed out after 15 minutes
FAILED`

Its running fine but taking time to install packages