# Register a shiny app as an asset in your project within IBM Watson Studio

Tags: r, shiny, ibm-cloud, rstudio, watson-studio

I am using the RStudio IDE in a Watson Studio Project to develop a shiny app. There is no problem to start the app from within the RStudio. 
My question here is how to deploy the app such that it is accessible with an URL from a normal browser.

I have found that the Watson Studio documentation talks about the deployment of an R shiny server when it is an asset in your project:

https://content-dsxlocal.mybluemix.net/docs/content/SSAS34_current/local-dev/mmd-create_deployment_asset_app.html

So the question is how to register the shiny app, which is developed in RStudio, as an shiny server asset to the Watson Studio project?

There is also a solution described here:
[Deploying R shiny to IBM Cloud server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50247903/deploying-r-shiny-to-ibm-cloud-server)

But it seems to be a bit outdated and I am looking for a solution within Watson Studio and without having to download all source files.

Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the feature you have found in the documentation is currently available on Watson Studio local only, but hope it will also be available in the public cloud soon (just recently, the Project import/export feature was made available in the public cloud, so it seems things are moving forward fast).

Meanwhile, you can e.g. use Kubernetes and Docker to deploy it on IBM Cloud (tutorial: https://github.com/holken1/deploying-r-on-cloud) and could use AppID and Kubernetes ingress to ensure proper application security.

Hope that helps.